# Android application doesn't trust certificate

Tags: android, certificate

I have a certificate to secure my site, certified by:  Thawte DV SSL CA, Thawte, Inc.

Now I made an android application that connects to a webservice from this site.
It used to work fine when just going for http://www.myserver.com.

But now that it's secured, and going for https://www.myserver.com I'm having some issues.

I use 2 phones to test my application.

- HTC Desire S with Android 2.3.3 (has SD card)
- Huawei Ideos X5 with Android 2.2.1 (no SD card)

The HTC does not have any problem connecting to the https.
The Huawei however gives a "Not trusted certificate exception".

The code I used to try and connect is the following:

```
public String performRequest(String message, String url, Context context) throws IOException {

    AndroidHttpClient hc = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android",context);
    Log.d(MobileConnectorApplication.APPLICATION_TAG, "NETWORK - Message to send: "+ message);
    HttpPost p = new HttpPost(url);

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, threeMinutes );
    p.setParams(httpParams);

    try{
        if (message != null)
            p.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    String response = "";

    HttpContext httpcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpcontext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, MobileConnectorApplication.COOKIE_STORE);
    try{
        HttpResponse resp = hc.execute(p,httpcontext);
        InputStream is = resp.getEntity().getContent();
        response = convertStreamToString(is);
        int httpResponsecode = resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() ;
        checkResponse(url, message, response, httpResponsecode);
        Log.d(MobileConnectorApplication.APPLICATION_TAG, String.format("NETWORK - Response %s : %s", httpResponsecode, response.length() > 150 ? response.subSequence(0, 150): response));

    } finally{
        hc.close();
    }
    return response;
 }
```

This part of the code was made by someone else a few months ago and he isn't around to change it and my knowledge about these connections isn't so great.

could someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should read these answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https